# quotes are rendered as symbol &quot;

Tags: html, rendering

i had css classes on bd. 
when seeing them on studio management the this is ok: 
`.box_blue {  background: url("../imgs/box_teste.png") no-repeat; #0087bd;  border: 1px solid #0d5875;  } .box_blue:hover {  background: #0087bd;  }`

but when i retrieve it from db to c# and saw it on vs12 html visualizer it's ok but when render to html the double quotes are replaced by `"&quot;"`
so... this is the result:

```
background: url(&quot;../imgs/box_teste.png&quot;) no-repeat; #0087bd;)
```

how can i render the thing to be correctly displayed?

Answer (score 2):

Quotes are not required for a URL in CSS. You can just leave them out.

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#background-image